# how to float 4 divs within another div

Tags: css, html

im trying to float 4 divs side by side. they are in a parent div width = 100% and each child div is width:25% there is no margin or padding either... they are not displaying correctly!

heres the code...

```
<div id="bottomsections">
    <div id="1a">
            <h1>a</h1>

        <p>This is Photoshop's version of Lorem Ipsum. Proin gravida nibh vel velit auctor aliquet. Aenean sollicitudin, lorem quis bibendum auctor, nisi elit consequat ipsum, nec sagittis sem nibh id elit. Duis sed odio sit amet nibh vulputate cursus a sit amet mauris. Morbi accumsan ipsum velit. Nam nec tellus a odio tincidunt auctor a ornare odio. Sed non mauris vitae erat consequat</p>
    </div>
    <div id="1b">
            <h1>b</h1>  
        <p>This is Photoshop's version of Lorem Ipsum. Proin gravida nibh vel velit auctor aliquet. Aenean sollicitudin, lorem quis bibendum auctor, nisi elit consequat ipsum, nec sagittis sem nibh id elit. Duis sed odio sit amet nibh vulputate cursus a sit amet mauris. Morbi accumsan ipsum velit. Nam nec tellus a odio tincidunt auctor a ornare odio. Sed non mauris vitae erat consequat</p>
    </div>
    <div id="1c">
            <h1>c</h1>  
        <p>This is Photoshop's version of Lorem Ipsum. Proin gravida nibh vel velit auctor aliquet. Aenean sollicitudin, lorem quis bibendum auctor, nisi elit consequat ipsum, nec sagittis sem nibh id elit. Duis sed odio sit amet nibh vulputate cursus a sit amet mauris. Morbi accumsan ipsum velit. Nam nec tellus a odio tincidunt auctor a ornare odio. Sed non mauris vitae erat consequat</p>
    </div>
    <div id="1d">
            <h1>d</h1>  
        <p>This is Photoshop's version of Lorem Ipsum. Proin gravida nibh vel velit auctor aliquet. Aenean sollicitudin, lorem quis bibendum auctor, nisi elit consequat ipsum, nec sagittis sem nibh id elit. Duis sed odio sit amet nibh vulputate cursus a sit amet mauris. Morbi accumsan ipsum velit. Nam nec tellus a odio tincidunt auctor a ornare odio. Sed non mauris vitae erat consequat</p>
    </div>
```

and css...

```
#bottomsections {
    width:100%;
}
#1a {
    width:25%;
    float:left;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#1b {
    width:25%;
    float:left;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#1c {
    width:25%;
    float:left;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#1d {
    width:25%;
    float:left;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

heres the fiddle..http://jsfiddle.net/aM2UL/1/

thanks!

Comment: And the floats are not (sure) cleared? `<div style="float: both;"></div>` below the 4 divs you have now.

Comment: A bunch of folks below say that you can't start an ID with a number. They're mistaken, at least for modern browsers. However, CSS hasn't caught up: http://benfrain.com/when-and-where-you-can-use-numbers-in-id-and-class-names

Comment: @isherwood the floats break because they aren't cleared (most likely at least, as we can't see that for sure). The OP can try 4x 20% to see if it's not a overflowing issue. If so, he/she can try to use `box-sizing: border-box;` to push outside pixels to the inside.

Comment: See my answer. No float clearing necessary.

Answer (score 6):

Id can not start with a number:

```
/* change #1a to #a1 */
#a1 {
    width:25%;
    float:left;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dfsq/aM2UL/3/

Refer this comprehensive answer about what characters are allowed: https://stackoverflow.com/a/449000/949476

*Upd*: As pointed by Allendar in comments you should also clear your floats. You can insert one more element after your floated divs with `clear: both`. Personally I use `.clearfix` class as more semantic:

```
.clearfix:before,.clearfix:after{content:"";display:table}
.clearfix:after{clear:both}
```

to be used as `<div id="bottomsections" class="clearfix">...</div>`

Comment: I use a `.floatClear` default class for it too dfsq +1 :)

Comment: @Allendar or even use `inline-block`'s :)

Comment: Your references are out of date, sir. :-)

Comment: @isherwood As far as I know lexical grammar rules have not changed. ID still can't start with a number. At least it will not work without hacks like yours. It's funny but not too practical.

Comment: Hack? Ouch. What grammar rules do you speak of if not HTML spec?

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-syntax/#syntax *In CSS3, identifiers ... cannot start with a digit or a hyphen followed by a digit*

Comment: thank you for all of your answers. Ive changed the names of the divs and added the clear floats and all is now working. thanks a ton

Answer (score 3):

You certainly **[can use numbers to start IDs](http://benfrain.com/when-and-where-you-can-use-numbers-in-id-and-class-names/)**, but you have to select them differently.

```
[id="1a"], [id="1b"], [id="1c"], [id="1d"] {
    width:25%;
    float:left;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aM2UL/11/

Comment: Wow this is interesting, never thought about this!

Answer (score 2):

id's cannot start with numbers in any revision of HTML and/or CSS, also, all 4 of your styles are the same, so you would be better off using a class such as

```
div.inner {
    width:25%;
    float:left;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

and set `<div id="1d" class="inner">`

this will keep your code smaller and more manageable and mean less changes if and when you need to do anything else to the code later on.

Answer (score 0):

```
#bottomsections div{ float:left; width:25%}
```

As others have said, numbers aren't valid beginnings to ids

Answer (score 0):

ids cant start with a number, try to change for #a1, or something. but if you want to apply the same properties in all divs of you main div, why you not do this way?

```
#bottomsections div{ 
    width:25%;
    float:left;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```